# Would this question be closed if I ask it on SO?

Tags: discussion

I asked the following question on the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14594/1357

On Stack Overflow there's a recommend tag. So that's why I'm asking if I can ask this question.

While I do know that the question belongs on the Software Recommendations site, I feel like if were allowed to post on SO, I would have a bigger chance of getting an answer. Because so many Android developers use SO and because my question can't be answered by just any programmer. They need to be an Android developer to understand the issue I'm having and to understand how much Android Studio sucks :)

I asked on XDA and many other forums but received no answers. I know many true geeks personally, yet haven't ben able to get an answer.

Comment: Yep, that would be closed. And there is no recommend tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommend

Comment: @Bart thank you, that's all i want to know :)

Comment: there is an [android.se site](http://android.stackexchange.com/), did you check that?

Comment: Sorry it popped up on my phone when i typed it on SO, not on pc right now, my mistake

Comment: @Sunshine yes, no recommend tag there

Comment: There is a recommendation tag on SO. But that concerns recommendation engines. Not general recommendations.

Comment: You can try android chatroom on SO or android.se chatrooms

Answer (score 1):

If you asked that on SO it should definitely be closed on SO for the reason of:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.